# Ajax File Upload And insert details and Form File Details to Db

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Please I Know that some of the Topics relating to my post is here but it does not actually seems to solve my problem. I have an uploader class and my Ajax upload is working fine without PHP connection. Now after Upload am trying to call in my file class to store the details to Database but not actually working out. I have searched all around both on youtube and none see to solve my problem

```
error_reporting(0);
if (isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {


$path = "uploads/"; //set your folder path
//set the valid file extensions 
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg", "GIF", "JPG", "PNG", "doc", "mp3", "txt", "docx", "pdf", "xls", "xlsx", "mp4"); //add the formats you want to upload

$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name']; //get the name of the file

$size = $_FILES['myfile']['size']; //get the size of the file

if (strlen($name)) { //check if the file is selected or cancelled after pressing the browse button.
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name); //extract the name and extension of the file
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) { //if the file is valid go on.
        if ($size < 9433098888) { // check if the file size is more than 2 mb
            $file_name  = $_POST['filename'];
            $new = $_POST['music_new'];  //get the file name
            $tmp        = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']; 

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $file_name.'.'.$ext)) { //

                 $sam->musicUpload('name','format','so on');

                //please am in need of this. if i type echo $file_name works but can actually insert to my db.. i have no problem with my back end

                }  

            else {
                echo "failed";
            }
        } else {
            echo "File size max 2 MB";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file format..";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please select a file..!";
}

include'../../header.php';

      echo $url;
}


<div class='category-tab shop-details-tab'><!--category-tab-->
<div class='col-sm-12'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <li><a href='#details' data-toggle='tab'>Details</a></li>
        <li><a href='#companyprofile' data-toggle='tab'>Company Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='#tag' data-toggle='tab'>Tag</a></li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#reviews' data-toggle='tab'>Reviews (5)</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='details' >
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class='product-image-wrapper'>
                <div class='single-products'>
                    <div class='productinfo text-center'>
                        <img src='images/home/gallery1.jpg' alt='' />
                        <h2>$56</h2>
                        <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='companyprofile' >

        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class='product-image-wrapper'>
                <div class='single-products'>
                    <div class='productinfo text-center'>
                        <img src='images/home/gallery4.jpg' alt='' />
                        <h2>$56</h2>
                        <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='tag' >

        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class='product-image-wrapper'>
                <div class='single-products'>
                    <div class='productinfo text-center'>
                        <img src='images/home/gallery4.jpg' alt='' />
                        <h2>$56</h2>
                        <p>Easy Polo Black Edition</p>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default add-to-cart'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i>Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='tab-pane fade active in' id='reviews' >
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=''><?php if($logged){ echo $username;}else{echo'Not Logged';}?></a></li>
                <li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i>12:41 PM</a></li>
                <li><a href=''><i class='fa fa-calendar-o'></i>31 DEC 2014</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p> Plese make sure to upload Relevant files or else it will be deleted by the Head  Admin(s). Thanks for Understanding</p>
            <p><b>Write Your Review</b></p>


        <div class="row">

    <div class='tab-pane fade active in' id='reviews' >
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <h3>jQuery Ajax file upload with percentage progress bar</h3>
            <form id="myform" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Enter the file name: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="filename" /> 
                </div>
             <span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Database Name"  id='music_name'/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Producer"" id="music_producer" />
                </span>
                <br>

                <span>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Artist Name"  id="music_artist"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Album Name"/>
                </span><br>
                  <textarea name="" placeholder="Music Description" id='music_desc'></textarea>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select file: </label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="myfile" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success myprogress" role="progressbar" style="width:0%">0%</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="msg"></div>
                </div>

                <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn-success" value="Upload" />
            </form>

             <?php   include'generalModal.php';
             ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div><!--/category-tab-->  






<?php

include_once'../../music/reCommend.php'; echo'
<script src="'.$url.'panel/uploadMusic/processUpload.js"></script>'; 

include '../../Blog/Footer.php';
```

Comment: Not a good idea to disable error reporting while trying to find problems in your code. Or do you consistently check the PHP error logs?

Comment: where is your ajax code?

Comment: Enable this: `ini_set('display_errors', true);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` and report back with your errors.

Comment: this is my ajax code